# Replace ctags with exuberant-ctags

Tags: linux-mint, apt, ctags

I am trying to install the `exuberant-ctags` package on Linux Mint. To do so I ran:

```
$ sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exuberant-ctags
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/120 kB of archives.
After this operation, 334 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package exuberant-ctags.
(Reading database ... 339129 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../exuberant-ctags_1%3a5.9~svn20110310-7ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking exuberant-ctags (1:5.9~svn20110310-7ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up exuberant-ctags (1:5.9~svn20110310-7ubuntu0.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant to provide /usr/bin/ctags (ctags) in auto mode
```

The last line suggests that `ctags-exuberant` is used instead of `ctags`.

When I, however, restart bash and run `ctags -e` I get the error:

```
ctags: invalid option -- 'e'
```

While the `-e` option is available in `exuberant-ctags`.

Why hasn't `exuberant-ctags` replaced `ctags`?

```
$ command -v ctags

/usr/local/bin/ctags
```

This is not what I want

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ctags

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Dec 28  2015 /usr/bin/ctags -> /etc/alternatives/ctags
```

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/ctags

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Aug  9 21:22 /etc/alternatives/ctags -> /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant
```

```
$ ctags --version

ctags (GNU Emacs 24.5)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed under the terms in ETAGS.README
```

Comment: Please update the question with the output of `command -v ctags` and `ls -l /usr/bin/ctags` and `ls -l /etc/alternatives/ctags` and `ctags --version`

Comment: @StephenHarris done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that your installation just added `exuberant-ctags` as an option for alternatives.

```
/usr/bin/update-alternatives --display ctags
```

If it is pointing to the wrong version you can manually set the alternative

```
sudo /usr/bin/update-alternatives --set ctags /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant
```

In your case, however (based on your question update) you have a non-packaged version of `ctags` in your PATH (`/usr/local/bin/ctags`) before the  packaged `ctags-exuberant` and `alternatives` version, so this is being called first.

You either need to remove that version, modify your `$PATH` or add a symlink to `/usr/bin/ctags` earlier in your path (perhaps `$HOME/bin`) so that you're running the version you want to run.

Comment: Thanks. It is pointing to the correct version though. `link currently points to /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant`.

Comment: When I run `/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant -e` it does work. As a quick hack I can create an alias like so: `alias ctags='/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant'`. Edit: this does not work since emacs apparently uses another shell.

Comment: Thanks. Removing this local ctags version did the trick. Thank you very much for your help! Glad to have learned the `command` command.